# Give user permission to change IP address from static to DHCP and vice-versa

Tags: permissions, ip, scripting, users, ubuntu-16.04

Let me start by saying I am somewhat of a Linux newb. I have inherited some basic Ubuntu systems to admin (Ubuntu 16.04). I have a couple users that need to plug their machines from the network to other (approved) devices as part of their development. I need to give these non-privileged users permissions to change their IP address from a static to DHCP and vice versa either through terminal or gui. I am unsure of how to approach this and any help of suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with Network-Manager it should be possible when u put those users in the **netdev** group.

you can use command line command:

```
sudo adduser fred netdev
```

see also the [ubuntu wiki] (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges#Connect_to_wireless_and_ethernet_networks)

Comment: did it work? when yes pls accept answer

Comment: YES!. It did work. Thanks for your help. The user can change his IP in GUI and in Terminal.